# How to mock Async Search?

Tags: c#

```
[Fact]
    public async Task Test_GetCustomer_Status_When_No_Customer_Exist()
    {
        var customerEngine = A.Fake<ICustomerEngine>();
        var monitorEngine = A.Fake<IMonitorEngine>();
        var customerLog = A.Fake<ILogProvider<CustomerManager>>();
        var conditions = new List<ScanCondition>();
        var customers = new List<Customer>();
        var names = new List<string>
        {
            "SERVICE"
        };
        var hashKey = "SITE";
        A.CallTo(() => customerEngine.GetCustomers(conditions)).Returns(null);  // Get customers returns AsyncSearch<Customer>
        A.CallTo(() => monitorEngine.QueryItems(hashKey, QueryOperator.BeginsWith, names)).Returns(null);
        CustomerManager manager = new CustomerManager(customerEngine, monitorEngine);
        await manager.GetCustomers();
        A.CallTo(() => customerEngine.GetCustomers(A<List<ScanCondition>>.Ignored)).MustHaveHappened();
    }
```

Get customers returns AsyncSearch

**But, How to mock AsyncSearch?
Is there any work around for this now?**

Comment: Why do you want to mock the result as well? By mocking the `GetCustomers` you can return any `AsyncSearch` object.

Comment: because getCustomers() returns AsyncSearch<Customer>

Comment: Let me try to give an example. Let's suppose you have a function which returns the day of the current month: `byte GetDayOfCurrentMonth()`. By mocking the method itself you can return any valid (1 ... 31) or invalid (0, 32 ...255) data. With mocking you are short cutting the calculation logic and returning a predefined "static" value instead. You can do the same by creating a new `AsyncSearch<Customer>` instance and specifying its properties as needed for the test case. If it is an *async method* then you should use the `Task.FromResult` to wrap the search object into a Task.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible now as of version 3.7.4.9 of the AWSSDK.DynamoDBv2 package, as Norm Johanson mentions on the [Github issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/772#issuecomment-1242558047). You can mock `AsyncSearch` by creating your own subclass as he shows, or by using Moq like so:

```cs
var mockAsyncSearch = new Mock<AsyncSearch<YourClass>>();

mockAsyncSearch
    .Setup(a => a.GetRemainingAsync(...))
    .Returns(...);
```

And then your mocked `IDynamoDbContext` can just use `.Returns(mockAsyncSearch.Object)` as usual.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see the interface for this class hence it would be tough to fake it. I see this issue reported to AWS, if they come back with an fix in future, we can do it. There is work around as you will end up in doing lot of R&D. Refer this https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/772 and
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/772